# Stored procedure returning customers a user cannot support

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, having

I've created a stored procedure to allocate a customer to a user based on the number and type of customer requests versus the skills of the user. Below is an extract of part of the stored procedure - status = 0 means unallocated.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    gdd.customerReference
FROM 
    customerRequests gdd
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    userSkills us ON us.requestTypeId = gdd.requestTypeId 
                  AND us.userId = @pinUserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    requestAttributes dt ON dt.requestTypeId = gdd.requestTypeId
WHERE 
    gdd.status = 0
GROUP BY 
    gdd.requestDateTime, gdd.customerReference, gdd.requestId, gdd.requestTypeId
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = COUNT(us.userId)
```

Example data:

Customer Requests

```
requestId   requestTypeId   policyNumber    customerReference   requestDateTime userId  status
1   3   Policy A    Customer 1  30/11/2015 10:13        0
2   4   Policy A    Customer 1  30/11/2015 10:33        0
3   11  Policy B    Customer 2  26/11/2015 15:26        0
4   17  Policy B    Customer 2  26/11/2015 15:27        0
5   1   Policy B    Customer 2  27/11/2015 10:05        0
```

Users skills:

```
skillId userId  requestTypeId
1   user1   3
2   user1   17
3   user1   11
4   user1   1
5   user2   1
6   user2   3
7   user4   4
```

Request attributes:

```
requestTypeId   description priority    tolerance
1   Type A  200 90
2   Type B  999 999999
3   Type C  100 7
4   Type D  100 5
5   Type E  50  5
6   Type F  100 999999
7   Type G  999 999999
8   Type H  999 999999
9   Type I  999 999999
10  Type J  999 999999
11  Type K  100 999999
12  Type L  999 999999
13  Type M  999 999999
14  Type N  999 999999
15  Type O  100 5
16  Type P  100 10
17  Type Q  100 10
```

By using TOP 1 in the select the query is correctly returning Customer 2 when I substitute `@pinUserId` with user1. The problem is that if I take TOP 1 out of the query I also see Customer 1 in the result set even though user1 is not able to handle both of Customer 1's requests. If Customer 1's requests came in before Customer 2 user1 would have been incorrectly allocated Customer 1.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: It is very interesting to me using `TOP 1` in a query without an `ORDER BY`.  Since SQL guarantees no ordering you are saying give me any random row.   Since you don't say can you please explain the business rules to pick this "correct" result?

Comment: Why do you even join to the RequestAttributes table?   It doesn't play any role in the query results.

Comment: Sorry missed the order by off of the statement : ORDER BY DATEDIFF(day, gdd.requestDateTime, GETDATE()) - dt.tolerance DESC, dt.priority, MIN(gdd.requestDateTime)